# Unable to access wp-includes files

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress website. It cannot access the js and css files at the wp-includes folder.

For example, I have a **sample.css** file then I am accessing **sample.com/about-us**. Then the console shows error that it can't find the said css file.
The error in the console shows that it's accessing the file via this URL, **sample.com/about-us/wp-includes/sample.css** when it should be accessing the file at this URL, **sample.com/wp-includes/sample.css**. When I type this to the browser I can access the file. I have fixed this error already ut May I ask why is this happening or how can I remove that "**/about**" in the URL to access my css file?

I hope you understand the question. Please do suggest edit so my question will be better to understand.

P.S.
I have resolved the error already but through editing a certain wordpress core file(which i forgot already) and adding base_url() at the beginning of the statement. I have update wordpress that's why it is overridden, so now, I would like to fix it without editing the core file.

Thank you! Much appreciated.

EDIT!

I believe this files should be accessed by wordpress correctly cause they are included in wordpress' core files. If I am not mistaken? Cause I can't find how these source files are accessed, not even in functions.php of my theme folder.

**sample.com/about/sample-url/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2** 
**sample.com/about/sample-url/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.x-xxxx1105**
**sample.com/about/sample-url/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2** 
**sample.com/about/sample-url/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1** 
**sample.com/about/sample-url/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4** 
**sample.com/about/sample-url/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=1.0**

Answer (score 1):

The link to the style sheet is relative when it needs to be absolute to the root of your application. It is `wp-includes/sample.css` instead of `/wp-includes/sample.css`. Notice the beginning slash.

Comment: That's the right root cause. A correctly configured wordpress and theme should handle that automatically. Maybe there is another issue at hand

Comment: I'll be trying this one. I'll give a feedback tomorrow when I'm able to access the server. Thank you!

Comment: One of the files I'm accessing at wp-includes is the thickbox.css file. FYI.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are calling this code to get the output you are seeing, but you may want to use something like this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: Hi @xarthnax. Yes, I'm going to include those files to be declared and used at my functions.php in case the problem will persist using what you've referenced and for the scripts.

Comment: As of now, I haven't figured it out. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, I was unable to access css and js files in wp-includes directory. After change the permission to 755 it works as expected.